# Flutter windows the semaphore timeout period has expired error

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, flutter-windows, timeouterror

I have developed an application running on windows with flutter. This application sends some requests to a server running on another windows device on the local network.
In this part, in some cases I get this error "**the semaphore timeout period has expired**". When I searched, I saw that it was a windows related error, but unfortunately I could not find a definite solution.
There is no problem with the internet connection. Except for the flutter application running on Windows, other applications communicate over the network and there is no problem with them.

I tried using dio instead of http packet but the result is the same.